# How I can read a json file each object by object?

Tags: json

I've got a problem with a json file... I want to read it but I don't know how to do that... 
My json :

```
[{"assurance":"Aquilana","typ_product":"TAR-BASE","product":"BASE"},{"assurance":"Aquilana","typ_produit":"Y","produit":"Z"}]
```

And I would like to have something like that :

```
<select><option value='MY TYPE PRODUCT'>MY PRODUCT</option></select>
```

Anyone can help me ?

Thanks !

Comment: You can use API like this: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/ with input file by user.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using any javascript libraries such as angularjs, jquery, knockoutjs?

I would suggest taking a look at angularjs or knockoutjs for binding your html to a modelview, in this case your json object.

Comment: Yes I use jquery-1.10.2.js

Comment: I would suggest that you take a look at knockoutjs and angularjs when it comes to binding your data to your DOM/html. angularjs uses jquery and is the framework that we currently use but knockoutjs might be easier to get started with: http://learn.knockoutjs.com

Here is a direct link to an example on how to bind select options to a viewmodel using knockoutjs:
http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/options-binding.html